# Scala type mismatch - found: Unit required: Array[String]

Tags: scala, type-mismatch, databricks

I do not understand why Scala complains about a type error in the following example:

```
def GetRanges(RangeString1: String): Array[String] = {
    val GetOneRange = "\\d+\\-\\d+".r;
    var AllRanges = new Array[String](0);
    if (!f_stringNullEmpty(RangeString1)) {
      GetOneRange.findAllIn(RangeString1).matchData.foreach(
        m => AllRanges = AllRanges ++ Array[String](m.group(0)) // Explicit casting to Array[String]
      )
    }
    return scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(AllRanges);
}
```

the error I receive is:

```
 notebook:38: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Array[String]
 return scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(AllRanges);
                                    ^
```

Apparently, iterating through the regex results and adding them to the array, causes a type change. But why?
Or did I miss something more fundamental?

Note: I understand that the if statement returns a type Unit, because no else was specified. But I can;t see that that would affect the type of my array.

Answer (score 1):

Return type of `scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(AllRanges)` is `Unit`. But, `GetRanges` requires `Array[String]`

```
def GetRanges(RangeString1: String): Array[String] = {
val GetOneRange = "\\d+\\-\\d+".r;
```

Here is `quickSort` for sorting Arrays

```
 /** Sort array `a` with quicksort, using the Ordering on its elements.
    * This algorithm sorts in place, so no additional memory is used aside from
    * what might be required to box individual elements during comparison.
    */
  def quickSort[K: Ordering](a: Array[K]): Unit = {
    // Must have iN >= i0 or math will fail.  Also, i0 >= 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

`quickSort()` mutates `AllRanges` in place and just returns `Unit`, but you've specified that `GetRanges()` returns `Array[String]` as if `quickSort()` was returning an `Array` (it's not).

You can fix your code by changing it to something like this (nb. you don't need to specify `return`):

```scala
scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(AllRanges)
AllRanges
```

FWIW, you can also avoid using `f_stringNullEmpty` and the array concatenation by doing something like this instead:

```
def getRanges(s: String): Array[String] = {
  val p = """\d+\-\d+""".r
  Option(s).filter(_.nonEmpty).map(p.findAllIn) match {
    case Some(matches) if matches.nonEmpty =>
      val m = matches.toArray[String]
      scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(m)
      m
    case _ =>
      Array.empty[String]
  }
}
```

Comment: Joey, thanks. I expected quickSort to return the ordered array, which indeed it does not. FYI The position of ^ in the error message got me to think that the argument to quickSort was of the wrong type, not that the return type of quickSort was of the wrong type. Learning day by day...